# Online store, best way to display a shirt with front and back graphic

Tags: e-commerce

I'm wondering what is the best way to display a shop item (on the shop index page) so that the customer is aware that there is a back graphic? I'm leaning towards possibly having a large diagonal line to show both the front and the back but the issue is that the placement of the graphics can cause issues.

I do not think a mouse over method will be suitable as this will not work with mobile devices.

[image: shop item]

Comment: Marketing answer (for a a unisex shirt): show a picture of a female model wearing (just) the shirt in front of a mirror, show a video of her turning around on activation (i.e. click/hover or tap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

- showing both a front and back view of the shirt in one photo/view.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a **vertical draggable separator** that reveals the front and back sides as you drag it with your mouse or finger.

Something like this:

[image: Mockup]

**Edit**: it depends on what you mean by "shop index page". If it's an array of dozens of items, then the best option would be to have front & back views side-by-side.

If, however, I assumed correctly and the "shop index page" is more like a "featured items" page, then I believe my solution would be better than a side-by-side view. Of course, it **works best with centered graphics**.

Comment: Why? This seems a bit gimmicky and also quite fiddly to use.

Comment: @JonW I have seen this in use on a couple of websites. It's actually quite intuitive and if implemented well, _non-fiddly_.

Comment: perhaps nod fiddly, but cumbersome if you're scanning a large selection of items. It lacks 'scanability'. (And gimmicks *can* be useful...sometimes it's the gimmick that provides delight. So they can work. I'd just consider them carefully)

Comment: @DA01 Edited answer for the "large selection of items" case.

Comment: @MarkoK good edit

Comment: Any reason why it goes from left to right and not top to bottom? I thought it might be more important or easier to see the design in a symmetrical view...

Comment: @MichaelLai A "left to right view" shows the whole shirt, how the sleeves and collar look from both sides etc. Top to bottom doesn't give you that. Another advantage is left-to-right being more natural to humans, as most of them read left to right as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following:

- A simple flip icon;
- Click/Tap on the image flips it (you would have to separate the click from image and title).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to have an action/button that indicates a flipping action, and a separate label that show whether it is the front of back of the shirt being shown (especially if it is not obvious because of the collar). This way you can separate the trigger from the image and perhaps allows you more flexibility in case you want to change your implementation later on.